# Update query that has same From and Join table reporting Ambiguous table error

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an `Update` query where the `from` table is the same as one of the join tables. It looks something like this

```
Update Contacts
Set NewContactId = repCt.Id
From Contacts ct
Join Contacts repCt on repCt.ClientId = ct.ClientId
                       AND <a bunch of other join criteria>
Where <a bunch of other criteria hitting both ct and repCt>
```

When I run this, I can an error that states `The table 'Contacts' is ambiguous`, implying that I cannot include the same table twice in my Update query. So how should I go about making this update (or is there a way around this)?

Comment: What are the odds: `ct.ClientId = ct.ClientId`? It fails for nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update ct --use the alias defined in from
Set NewContactId = repCt.Id
From Contacts ct
Join Contacts repCt on ct.ClientId = repCt.ClientId
                       AND <a bunch of other join criteria>
Where <a bunch of other criteria hitting both ct and repCt>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query as well

```
MERGE INTO Contacts ct
USING Contacts repCt
ON (ct.ClientId = ct.ClientId
AND <a bunch of other join criteria>)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
SET NewContactId = repCt.Id
WHERE <a bunch of other criteria hitting both ct and repCt>;
```

While updating try to use MERGE function rather than joins

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by making the entire `from...join` part of the query into one nested subquery, and then joined that instead. So the final result looks like this:

```
Update Contacts
Set NewContactId = t.newId
From Contacts ct
Join (
    select ct.Id, r.Id
    from contacts ct
    join contacts r on ct.clientid = r.clientid
    <all of the joins>
) as t on ct.Id
```